# Exception gets executed twice and it gets caught by a different except block

Tags: python, exception, recursion, import

I have the following code:

**file1.py**

```
from file2 import tfun

class TestException(Exception):
    pass

try:
    print 'I am running'
    tfun()
except TestException as e:
    print 'I am caught'
    print type(e)
except Exception as e:
    print 'I am generally caught'
    print type(e)
```

**file2.py**

```
def tfun():
    from file1 import TestException
    raise TestException()
```

and the output from `python file1.py` is the following:

```
I am running
I am running
I am caught
<class 'file1.TestException'>
I am generally caught
<class 'file1.TestException'>
```

First of all why the code gets executed twice in this case? I can understand that the import is recursive but why the code of the script get executed again?

Secondly, the second time it is not getting caught by the same `except` block even though it is the same type as the first time, which also I cannot find an explanation for.

Finally, I am trying to find a workaround for this problem without moving anything to a new file but I it does not seem to be any. Is it possible to get over this problem?

**Edit**

For the second question I realized it is because the code is inside the module level.

Comment: +1 for a short, complete, standalone program that demonstrates the problem at hand. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://SSCCE.org

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> > If you run a module as a script (i.e. give its name to the interpreter, rather than importing it), it’s loaded under the module name `__main__`.
> >
> > If you then import the same module from your program, it’s reloaded and reexecuted under its real name. If you’re not careful, you may end up doing things twice.
> >
> > http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

Your are loading `file1.py` twice, as two distinct modules. The first time it is loaded as a reesult of your command line:

```
python file1.py
```

In that case, file1.py is being loaded as the main module, `__main__`.

The second time you are loading it as a result of your import statement:

```
from file1 import TestException
```

In that case, file1.py is being loaded as the module `file1`.

Because file1.py is being loaded as two distinct modules, there are two distinct copies of everything in it. Particularly `__main__.TestException` is different from `file1.TestException`.

So, inside `__main__`, the line:

```
except TestException as e:
```

is catching `__main__.TestException` even as `tfun()` is raising `__file1__.TestException`. Inside `file1`, that same line is catching `file1.TestException`.

In the former case, the types do not match and the `except:` clause is not run; in the latter case the type does match and the `except:` clause is run.

Perhaps this program can make it more clear what is happening:

```
from file2 import tfun

class TestException(Exception):
    pass

try:
    print 'I am calling file2.tfun from', __name__
    tfun()
    print 'I have called file2.tfun from', __name__
except TestException as e:
    print 'I am caught in %s'%(__name__)
    print type(e), TestException
except Exception as e:
    print 'I am generally caught in %s'%__name__
    print type(e), TestException
print 'I am exiting from',__name__
```

Result:

```
$ python file1.py 
I am calling file2.tfun from __main__
I am calling file2.tfun from file1
I am caught in file1
<class 'file1.TestException'> <class 'file1.TestException'>
I am exiting from file1
I am generally caught in __main__
<class 'file1.TestException'> <class '__main__.TestException'>
I am exiting from __main__
```

A simple workaround is to modify file2.py:

```
def tfun():
    from __main__ import TestException
    raise TestException()
```

Result:

```
$ python file1.py 
I am calling file2.tfun from __main__
I am caught in __main__
<class '__main__.TestException'> <class '__main__.TestException'>
I am exiting from __main__
```

Comment: +1 The distinction between `__main__.TestException` and `file1.TestException` is the trickiest part, I think.